# External Links Not Working

Tags: links

I am facing a problem that external links are not working in [my website](http://thepocketpenny.com/). I am clicking on links but nothing happens. There are no popups, or broken links, but still not working. Why?

Comment: Links work on the site for me. Probably an issue with your browser or some kind of browser extension.

Comment: I have checked links on many browsers its working on only google chrome. why?? I have also tested it on android mobile device still not working

Comment: I've checked on Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer - all the links I clicked work just fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of every browser but still facing the problem. I don't know why??
but links work for me when I login to wordpress admin panel.

Answer (score 4):

This question is really too localized to get a solid answer and will most likely get closed. Here's a quick guide to narrow down what the issue is - but the fact that I can click the links just fine and you can't makes it sound like an issue with your system and not necessarily WordPress:

```
            Site Broken?
          /              \
        Nope        Enable Debugging
        /                   \
    Carry on        Site still broken?
                    /           \
                  Nope       Disable All Plugin
                  /                 \
              Carry On          Site still broken?
                                /       \
                            Nope        Switch to default theme
                            /           Like Twenty Sixteen Theme
                        Enable Plugins One  \
                        By One to find the   \
                        culprit. Uninstall    \
                                            Site still broken?
                                            /   \
                                         Nope   Reinstall WordPress and
                                          /     Contact your provider
                                    Find new theme
```

In case the above tree isn't clear, follow these steps:

1. [Enable Debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)
2. Disable Plugins

   1. If this solves your issue, enable plugins one by one and find the culprit, disable that plugin or contact the plugin developer.
3. Switch to the [default theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/)

   1. If this solves your issue then you know the theme is the problem which helps narrow it down. Find a new theme or contact the theme developer.
4. Reinstall WordPress

   1. May be a bad install which is solved by reinstalling WordPress
5. Your hosting provider may know something that we don't and can help you further.
6. Try it on a different computer, device, browser.